# Shiny R Session Aborted when pressing actionButton

Tags: r, button, shiny, abort

I'm facing a problem I can't resolve even with `options(shiny.trace=TRUE)`

It is a webapp that uploads a file and then you click that button to `scan()` the file you uploaded. When you upload the file all works well. But when you forget uploading the file, the actionButton makes Shiny to abort R, because "R encountered a fatal error".

The output of the debugging function is "RCV {"method":"update","data":{"button:shiny.action":1}} before it aborts.

Before the scan function I write a `if(input$button > 0 && !is.null(uploadedFile))` but it stills aborts. (This `if` statement is within an `observe({})` statement.

I've searched around the web but there's nobody who has faced this problem, it seems the problem is within the call of the actionButton...  that doesn't manage to do "nothing" when is pressed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Was a "variable naming" problem. And after finding that, I realized the button wasn't needed in the webapp. Thank you all